# Update attribute in MagicalRecord

Tags: objective-c, persistence, magicalrecord

I have an 'Animal' model that has a 'name' string, and 'mood' string as attributes. For whatever reason, I would like to use Core Data, and at the same time, would like to make it possible to update the attribute 'mood', when the user wants to update/edit/annotate that item.

Currently, I have an account annotation view, and the UITextFields create a new entry, and push to array, using

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    Animal* animal = [Animal MR_createInContext:context];
    animal.name = nameField.text;
    animal.mood = moodField.text;

    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];
```

and I can access my latest annotation using

```
    NSArray* allMyAnimals = [Animal MR_findAll];
        if (allMyAccounts.count > 0) {
            NSInteger animalIndex = allMyAccounts.count;
            Animal* myAnimal = allMyAnimals[animalIndex - 1];
        }
```

I was wondering, is there some way I can update the 'mood' attribute, instead of creating/pushing a new model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'll have to take a back seat on this one, although I found that NSIncrementalStore may be a good fit for the job or in between.